# Java JPA with MySql Workbench issue, netbeans Error Code: 1054

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, jpa

In my database I've got 3 tables **[click on staff to see MySql DB]**

- **[staff](http://s2.postimg.org/tz9qexb8p/staff.png)** {sid, sname}
- **[teachingstaff](http://s8.postimg.org/yy8cdahph/teachstaff.png)** {sid, qualification, subjectexpertise}
- **nonteachingstaff** {sid, areaexpertise}

sid in teachinstaff, nonteachingstaff - foreign key from staff
and I've set up autoincrement primary key in staff table

I will just instantiate teachingstaff and nonteachingstaff and like ending result i'd like to have something like this:

table

- **staff** (1-Bob, 2-Mike, 3-Tom, 4-Kyle)
- **teachinstaff** (1-"Good"-"A", 3-"Excellent"-"B")
- **nonteachingstaff** (2-"C", 4-"D")

Here's my code, and I don't know where I am wrong.

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Staff implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int sid;
    private String sname;

    public Staff(  String sname ) {
        this.sname = sname;
    }

    public Staff( ) {
       super( );
    }

    public int getSid( ) {
       return sid;
    }

    public void setSid( int sid ) {
       this.sid = sid;
    }

    public String getSname( ) {
       return sname;
    }

    public void setSname( String sname ) {
       this.sname = sname;
    } 
}
***************************************************************
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "sid")
public class TeachingStaff  extends Staff {

   private String qualification;
   private String subjectexpertise;

   public TeachingStaff(String sname, String qualification,String subjectexpertise) {
      super(sname);
      this.qualification = qualification;
      this.subjectexpertise = subjectexpertise;
   }

   public TeachingStaff( ) {
   }

   public String getQualification( ){
      return qualification;
   }

   public void setQualification( String qualification ){
      this.qualification = qualification;
   }

   public String getSubjectexpertise( ) {
      return subjectexpertise;
   }

   public void setSubjectexpertise( String subjectexpertise ){
      this.subjectexpertise = subjectexpertise;
   }

}
***************************************************************
@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "sid")
public class NonTeachingStaff extends Staff {

   private String areaexpertise;

   public NonTeachingStaff(String sname, String areaexpertise ) {
      super(sname);
      this.areaexpertise = areaexpertise;
   }

   public NonTeachingStaff( ) {
   }

   public String getAreaexpertise( ) {
      return areaexpertise;
   }

   public void setAreaexpertise( String areaexpertise ) {
      this.areaexpertise = areaexpertise;
   }

}
***************************************************************

    EntityManagerFactory emf =     Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("vezbaPU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction t = em.getTransaction();
    t.begin();

    //Teaching staff entity 
    TeachingStaff ts1 = new TeachingStaff("Gopal","MSc MEd","Maths");
    TeachingStaff ts2 = new TeachingStaff( "Manisha", "BSc BEd", "English");

    //Non-Teaching Staff entity
    NonTeachingStaff nts1 = new NonTeachingStaff("Satish", "Accounts");
    NonTeachingStaff nts2 = new NonTeachingStaff("Krishna", "Office Admin");

    em.persist(ts1);
    em.persist(ts2);
    em.persist(nts1);
    em.persist(nts2);

    t.commit();
    em.close();
    emf.close();
```

And when I try to compile and run a program I've got:

```
*run:
[EL Info]: 2016-01-06 15:02:55.407--ServerSession(978599729)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2016-01-06 15:02:55.707--ServerSession(978599729)--file:/C:/Users/korisnik/Documents/NetBeansProjects/vezba/build/classes/_vezbaPU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2016-01-06 15:02:55.807--UnitOfWork(1054913783)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'DTYPE' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: INSERT INTO STAFF (SID, SNAME, DTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(entiteti.NonTeachingStaff@18d910b3)
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'DTYPE' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: INSERT INTO STAFF (SID, SNAME, DTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(entiteti.NonTeachingStaff@18d910b3)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:157)
    at aa.proba.main(proba.java:38)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'DTYPE' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: INSERT INTO STAFF (SID, SNAME, DTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [3 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(entiteti.NonTeachingStaff@18d910b3)*
```

Comment: The Entity has been defined using a discriminator (column name = DTYPE) yet you haven't bothered adding this to your schema (as the message says "Unknown column 'DTYPE' "). Far easier if you let the JPA provider generate the schema

Comment: @engineer I'm really sorry for all mistakes, Im really new to stackoverflow, thanks a lot for editing :)

Comment: According to your description (`staff {sid, sname}`) you have 2 columns in the `STAFF` table, but you try to insert 3 fields `INSERT INTO STAFF (SID, SNAME, DTYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`. Focus on this problem.

Comment: I just want to put i.e I'm persisting: TeachingStaff("Gopal","MSc MEd","Maths") and as a result I want to have new row in each staff and teachingstaff tables (staff {1, "Gopal"}, teachingstaff(1,"MSc MEd", "Maths")). Honestly I'd like to try avoiding that DTYPE as long as I really dont need it.

Comment: The JPA spec doesn't say whether a JPA implementation has to use a discriminator when using JOINED strategy, so leaves it up to the JPA provider to decide. Some JPA implementations leave it to the user to put @DiscriminatorColumn to say yes I want a discriminator, but seemingly EclipseLink just gives you one regardless so you're stuck with it